# closure of a sequence of pairwise disjoint closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X_{i}$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint closed homeomorphic copies of $T_{2}$ space .
If $\bigcup _{i =1}^{\infty} X_{i}$   is closed, then what is the
closure of  $\bigcup _{i =2}^{\infty} X_{i}?$

Comment: Where did you see this question, or how did you come up with it? What have you tried?

Comment: @dfeuer, Well not much I could come up with except reducing the question to that: could a point in $X_{1}$ be a limit point of $\bigcup _{i =2}^{\infty} X_{i}$

Comment: Yes, well, where did this question come from? Do you know if there's supposed to be a nice answer? Because I really don't see anything to help you do this, unless these are in some specific space, like the real line.

Comment: @dfeuer, You can consider the space is Huasdorff if this helps

Comment: For the third and last time, where did this question come from?

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to say that the spaces $X_k$ are closed and to talk about the closure of $\bigcup_{k\ge 1}X_k$ only if this union is a subset of some topological space $Y$, so I’ll assume that this is the case and that $\bigcup_{k\ge 1}X_k$ and each of the subspaces $X_k$ is closed in $Y$. Let $Z=\bigcup_{k\ge 2}X_k$; we want to find $\operatorname{cl}_YZ$.

Clearly $\bigcup_{k\ge 1}X_k$ is a closed set containing $Z$, so $\operatorname{cl}_YZ\subseteq\bigcup_{k\ge 1}X_k$. Thus, $$(\operatorname{cl}_YZ)\setminus Z\subseteq\left(\bigcup_{k\ge 1}X_k\right)\setminus Z=X_1\;.$$ That is, if $Z$ has any limit points outside of itself, they must be in $X_1$. Unfortunately, we can’t say much more than this without further information.

- It’s possible that $Z$ is closed. As an example, let $Y=\Bbb Z^+$ with the discrete topology, and for $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $X_k=\{k\}$.
- It’s possible that $\operatorname{cl}_YZ=Y$. For this example let $Y=\Bbb Q$ with the usual topology. Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\Bbb Q$ by $p\sim q$ iff $p-q\in\Bbb Z$. Then $\sim$ has countably infinitely many equivalence classes, each of which is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ with the discrete topology; let $\{X_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ be the set of these equivalence classes, and without loss of generality assume that we’ve indexed them so that $X_1=\Bbb Z$. (Clearly $\Bbb Z$ is one of the $\sim$-classes.) Then $Z=\bigcup_{k\ge 2}X_k=\Bbb Q\setminus\Bbb Z$ is dense in $\Bbb Q$, so its closure is all of $\Bbb Q$, and of course $\bigcup_{k\ge 1}X_k=\Bbb Q$ is closed in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Thank you. As I thought we can't say much.

Comment: @Salem: You’re welcome.